# Heap diagnostics seem to be available using Qt Creator for MinGW, but I can't access them

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, mingw32, heap-corruption

I have a C++ GUI project built for 32-bit MinGW 7.30 using Qt Creator 4.9.2 for Qt 5.12.4. When I run my project from Qt Creator in debug mode (in Windows 10), I am getting error messages from deep in the bowels of the QTreeView code, of the form

> HEAP: Free Heap block 2E185810 modified at 2E185858 after it was freed

This means that Qt is running heap diagnostics. But I can't find out how to access these diagnostics programatically, to find the source of the problem. (I am assuming that the fault lies with my code and not with Qt, although this is obviously not 100% guaranteed.) The Windows diagnostic tools such as `_CrtMemoryCheck` are #defined out in the MinGW header files.

Does anybody know why these diagnostics are not available for MingW? Is it possible that they simply don't work, that Qt is running them anyway, and the error messages are spurious? If the errors are genuine, is there any way to find out more about them?

Comment: `_CrtMemoryCheck` is part of the MSVC C runtime library. MinGW will be using the GNU tool chain and it's C runtime library. You probably want to look for a Valgrind Windows implementation or alternative.

Comment: @RichardCritten: So where are those error messages coming from? If Qt can do it, why can't I?